# Manually adding change password

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to provide change password functionality to user manually through their profile page. Authenticated user can change their password. 
I have this form:

```
<form id="changePassword" method="post" action="{{ url('/changePassword', [$user->id]) }}">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}

                                <div class="col-md-6">

                                <label for="password">Old Password</label> 
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="oldPassword" required>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-5"> 
                                <label for="newPassword">New Password</label>  <b style ="color:red">*</b>
                                    <input type="password" id="newPassword" class="form-control" name="newPassword"  required><br>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-5"> 
                                <label for="password-confirm">Confirm Password</label>  <b style ="color:red">*</b>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation"  required><br>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Change Password
                                </button>
                                </div>
                                </form>
```

And this function in controller:

```
    public function changePassword(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user=User::where('id',$id)->first();
        if($user && auth()->user('password')==bcrypt($request->oldPassword))
        {
            return 'ok'; 

        }


   return 'No';          
    }
```

but if condition is never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code

```
use Hash;
use Auth;

public function changePassword(Request $request, $id) {

    $user = User::where('id',$id)->first();

    // Old password ( already saved in DB )
    $old_password = $request['old_pass'];

    // New password ( To be updated )
    $new_password = $request['new_pass'];

    // if password in DB matches the password provided
    if ($user && (Hash::check($old_password, $user->password)))  {

      // Hashing new password
      $hash_newpass = Hash::make($new_password);

      // Updating the hashed password
      User::where('id', $id)->update(['password' => $hash_newpass]);
    }

    else {
     // code for failure
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `bcrypt()` generates different hash at different times. So, `bcrypt($request->oldPassword)` will not be equal to the hash stored in database.Try printing `bcrypt('secret')` two different times and observe the difference.

Use [`Hash::check()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing) instead.

```
$user=User::where('id',$id)->first();
if(Hash::check($request->oldPassword, $user->password))
 {
    //statement    
}
```